# Get php array with with android

Tags: php, android

I've an error that occur when I try to fix it but it doesn't fix.

```
JSONArray application_band =jsonResponse.getJSONArray("banda");
String [] list = new String[application_band.length()];
for(int i = 0; i<application_band.length(); i++){
list[i] = application_band.getString(i);
}
```

And this when I create the intent:

```
 if (hurado_section ==1) {
Intent intent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, CategoryOneActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("hurado_name", hurado_name);
intent.putExtra("hurado_id", hurado_id);
intent.putExtra("hurado_section", hurado_section);
 intent.putExtra("application_band",list);
LoginActivity.this.startActivity(intent);
}
```

Error:

```
07-20 16:47:10.781 27808-27808/com.example.cursoft.scoringsystemseu W/System.err: org.json.JSONException: No value for banda
```

What could be the problem?

Comment: `banda` doesn't appear anywhere in your code...

Comment: "array"ust be banda

Comment: What does jsonResponse contain?

Comment: The jsonResponse contain success